# How do I complete the anglers quests?

Tags: terraria-mobile

When I found the angler, he told me to get a mushroom. One that apparently bites and swims around. So I went into the blue mushroom biome, picked some mushrooms, and went back. He still said that he wanted a snapping mushroom. Earlier today he told me to kill a fish with feathers and a woman's head, which I guessed was a harpy. I killed one, and went back with the feather. He still said to kill a flying fish with feathers and a woman's head.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Angler isn't asking for mushrooms and feathers.  He's asking for fish.

All of the little missions he will give you require you to fish in a certain area until you get a rare catch, which is what he's looking for.  The biomes that you went to are certainly good starts; many of the rare catches can only be found in certain biomes, and you are already matching that up with the descriptions he is giving.  You just need to start fishing, and keep doing it until you get the proper fish.